# Could not find the default element c#

Tags: c#

I have a very strange problem. I build a program that has a conection with some service references.
Until yesterday it was working great. I don't know what happened and now when I try to communicate with those services it gives me the error

```
  System.InvalidOperationException:  Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'DateMovementRetrievalServiceProduction.DateMovementRetrievalPortType' in the service model client ServiceModel section. This might be because no configuaration file was found for your application or because no end point element matching this contract could be found in the client element
in System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
   in System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName, Configuration configuration)
   in System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName)
   in System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
   in System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   in System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
   in System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateChannelFactory()
   in System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait)
   in System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
   in System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor()
   in WcfWsClient.DateMovementRetrievalServiceProduction.DateMovementRetrievalPortTypeClient..ctor() in \IcisNet.WcfWsClient\Service References\DateMovementRetrievalServiceProduction\Reference.cs:line 837
   in IcisNet.WcfWsClient.DateMovementRetrievalProductionClient.RetrieveDateMovements(IcisNetSecurityToken token, DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, DomainRolesIcisNet domainRole, DomainsIcisNet domain) in IcisNet.WcfWsClient\DateMovementRetrievalProductionClient.cs:line 15
  in IE.Forms.IcisNetStatusForm.GetIcisNetMessagesByDates() in IE.Forms\IcisNetStatusForm.cs:line 120
```

I dont know if this the correct translation of the error because I have the exception in Greek.
The funny thing is that the program works fine under visual studio debbuging but gives me  the exception only when I run the executable from \debug\ folder.

I tried to reverse commit from bitbucket but it still gives me that error. If I run the executable from previous builds it works fine.

In DateMovementRetrievalServiceProduction\Reference.cs lines 833-855

```
 [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public partial class DateMovementRetrievalPortTypeClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<Ektelonistis.IcisNet.WcfWsClient.DateMovementRetrievalServiceProduction.DateMovementRetrievalPortType>, Ektelonistis.IcisNet.WcfWsClient.DateMovementRetrievalServiceProduction.DateMovementRetrievalPortType {

        public DateMovementRetrievalPortTypeClient() {
        }

        public DateMovementRetrievalPortTypeClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName) {
        }

        public DateMovementRetrievalPortTypeClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public DateMovementRetrievalPortTypeClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
        }

        public DateMovementRetrievalPortTypeClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress) {
        }
```

In file DateMovementRetrievalProductionClient.cs lines 8-18
      public class DateMovementRetrievalProductionClient : IDateMovementRetrievalServiceContract
        {
            #region Implementation of IDateMovementRetrievalServiceContract

```
        public List<RetrieveMovementInfo> RetrieveDateMovements(IcisNetSecurityToken token, DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, 
            DomainRolesIcisNet domainRole, DomainsIcisNet domain)
        {
            using (DateMovementRetrievalPortTypeClient client = new DateMovementRetrievalPortTypeClient())
            {

                //Production enviroment force TLS 1.2 
.
.
.
```

and in file IcisNetStatusForm.cs lines 110-120

```
 IDateMovementRetrievalServiceContract client = DateMovementRetrievalFactory.
                    GetDateMovementRetrievalService(
                        Parameters.Config.IsTestService ? MessageServiceType.Test : MessageServiceType.Production);

                string afm = DefaultDiasafistis.DiasafistisDefault.Afm;

                if ((int)lookUpEditEvrosAnazitisis.EditValue == 1 &&
                    lookUpEditPelates.EditValue != null)
                    afm = lookUpEditPelates.EditValue.ToString();

                List<RetrieveMovementInfo> movementInfos = client.RetrieveDateMovements(new IcisNetSecurityToken
```

and finally because I searched why this problem can happen and most of the answers say that it has something to do with app.config this is my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyConfigBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="TimeServiceImplPortBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="TimeServiceImplPortBinding1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="MessageProcessorPortBinding">
          <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" requireDerivedKeys="true" includeTimestamp="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="MovementRetrievalPortBinding">
          <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" requireDerivedKeys="true" securityHeaderLayout="Lax" includeTimestamp="true" keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy" messageSecurityVersion="Default">
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="DateMovementRetrievalPortBinding">
          <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" requireDerivedKeys="true" securityHeaderLayout="Lax" includeTimestamp="true" keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy" messageSecurityVersion="Default">
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="MessageProcessorPortBinding1">
          <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" requireDerivedKeys="true" includeTimestamp="true" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="MovementRetrievalPortBinding1">
          <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" requireDerivedKeys="true" securityHeaderLayout="Lax" includeTimestamp="true" keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy" messageSecurityVersion="Default">
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="DateMovementRetrievalPortBinding1">
          <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Default" authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" requireDerivedKeys="true" securityHeaderLayout="Lax" includeTimestamp="true" keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy" messageSecurityVersion="Default">
            <secureConversationBootstrap />
          </security>
          <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous" realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false" useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint bindingConfiguration="MyConfigBinding" name="SignInvoice" address="http://localhost:8731/SignHere" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Sign.Contracts.ISignDocument" />
      <endpoint address="https://www2.gsis.gr:443/wsicisnet/MessageProcessorService" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MessageProcessorPortBinding" contract="MessageProcessorServiceTest.MessageProcessorPortType" name="MessageProcessorPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://www2.gsis.gr:443/wsicisnet/MovementRetrievalService" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MovementRetrievalPortBinding" contract="MovementRetrievalServiceTest.MovementRetrievalPortType" name="MovementRetrievalPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://www2.gsis.gr:443/wsicisnet/DateMovementRetrievalService" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="DateMovementRetrievalPortBinding" contract="DateMovementRetrievalServiceTest.DateMovementRetrievalPortType" name="DateMovementRetrievalPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://www1.gsis.gr:443/wsicisnet/MessageProcessorService" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MessageProcessorPortBinding1" contract="MessageProcessorServiceProduction.MessageProcessorPortType" name="MessageProcessorPort1" />
      <endpoint address="https://www1.gsis.gr:443/wsicisnet/MovementRetrievalService" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MovementRetrievalPortBinding1" contract="MovementRetrievalServiceProduction.MovementRetrievalPortType" name="MovementRetrievalPort1" />
      <endpoint address="https://www1.gsis.gr:443/wsicisnet/DateMovementRetrievalService" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="DateMovementRetrievalPortBinding1" contract="DateMovementRetrievalServiceProduction.DateMovementRetrievalPortType" name="DateMovementRetrievalPort1" />
      <endpoint address="https://www2.gsis.gr:443/wsicisnet/TimeService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TimeServiceImplPortBinding" contract="TimeServiceTest.TimeServiceImpl" name="TimeServiceImplPort" />
      <endpoint address="https://www1.gsis.gr:443/wsicisnet/TimeService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TimeServiceImplPortBinding1" contract="TimeServiceProduction.TimeServiceImpl" name="TimeServiceImplPort1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" /></startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.10.0" newVersion="2.6.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.10.0" newVersion="2.6.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.29.0" newVersion="2.2.29.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you checked that the services are available? Or failing that have they been updated with breaking changes?

Comment: Yes those services are available and I use them when I run the program from visual studio

Comment: Have you verified that the /debug folder contains your app configuration when running in debug mode?

Comment: When I run in debuf mode there is no client.exe.vshost.config file but it works fine.
When I run it as executable where the client.exe.config exists it doesnt work

Comment: I changed the language to give me the exception in english, so the exact exception is : 
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'DateMovementRetrievalServiceProduction.DateMovementRetrievalPortType' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem.
It had nothing to do with the app.config or anything from the program.
The problem was with a program that I use to lock my program and for some reason it blocks the communication with the services.
Thank you all for your time